# How do I create a Google Map using v3 API with clickable markers with custom html inside the marker?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a database full of addresses and pictures of those locations. Note: I do not have the latitude / longitude.

What I need to do:

Write a function that uses Google API v3 to list a few of these addresses on a Google map, that when you click on the marker, it displays the address and the picture from the database. This is a plugin for a page, so I cannot edit the header data. I can only insert code where it is being displayed.

I've already read through the documentation but it seems like everything has a lot of unnecessary code and stuff that my geomap doesn't need. I'm looking for the simplest possible solution so that I can add to it later if I want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the red marker on the map I've made here: http://www.dougglover.com/samples/UOITMap/index.html

Is that about what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try Gmapper (http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmapper/) a nice php class to do Google Maps. It's a simple way to generate all the javascript and it can also look up addresses. Be aware that Google limits the number of lookups for addresses, you probably won't be able to retrieve your db in one day.

Comment: It was last updated a year ago. Does it run on api v3? V3 doesnt require an API key and doesn't have limits IIRC.

Comment: I'm not sure if it uses V3. I does need a key. Seems like this is not a solution for you, sorry for that.

Comment: No problem. I hope someone else can help :)

Comment: V3 looks quite similar to what this tool creates, maybe you can adapt it?

Answer (score 1):

Can I point you at a site I did pretty much exactly that (except it updates when you hover a marker rather than click on it; just move the code into the empty click event provided rather than the hover event). In the spirit of real coding, hopefully you can adapt what I've done!

[http://www.primrose-house.co.uk/localattractions](http://www.primrose-house.co.uk/localattractions?script=no)

Comment: Click on the "Click here to see the attractions on a map" link :)

Sorry I forgot we'd changed it to default to the non-map behaviour :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    Here is the full html with google map api v3, markers will be create on dragging the route and then each marker having custom html inside the infowindow.

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var rendererOptions = {
  draggable: true,
  suppressInfoWindows: true
  };
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var map;
var total;
var waypoint_markers = []

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.87916, -3.32910),
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
};
var markers = [];

function init() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP});

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  //directionsDisplay.setPanel($("#directionsPanel")[0]);

  google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
    watch_waypoints();
  });
  calcRoute(false);
}

function calcRoute(waypoints) {
  var selectedMode = "DRIVING"; //document.getElementById("mode").value;
  var ary;
  if(waypoints) {
    ary = waypoints.map(function(wpt) {return {location: wpt, stopover: false};});
  } else {
    ary = [];
  }

  var request = {
    origin: "Seattle, WA",
    destination: "Portland, OR",
    waypoints: ary,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem["IMPERIAL"]
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

function watch_waypoints() {
  clear_markers();
  var wpts = directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoints;
  for(var i=0; i<wpts.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        //icon: "/images/blue_dot.png",
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(wpts[i].lat(), wpts[i].lng()),
        title: i.toString(),
        draggable :true
        });
    waypoint_markers.push(marker);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
    content: "<table>" +
    "<tr><td>Waypoint:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name' value=''/> </td> </tr>" +
    "<tr><td>Waypoint Description:</td> <td><input type='text' id='address' value=''/></td> </tr>" +
    "<tr><td><input type='hidden' value='"+marker.getPosition()+"'id='hiddenval'></td></tr>"+
    "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Save & Close' onclick='saveData(<?php print_r(node_load(arg(1))->nid);?>)'/></td></tr>"
});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);

    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function() {
        marker.setMap(null);
        wpts.splice(parseInt(this.title), 1);
        calcRoute(wpts);
        directionsDisplay.setOptions({ preserveViewport: true, draggable: true});
    });
  }
}
function clear_markers() {
  for(var i=0; i<waypoint_markers.length; i++){
    waypoint_markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
<div id="directionsPanel"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```